# mysql: table disappeared. I have never dropped it

Tags: mysql

I was trying to drop a column of my table but I got an error message.

After a few attempts, suddenly the table disappeared, but I have never dropped it.

I was in the page "table structure" of phpmyadmin, I clicked "drop column" and an error message appeared, which told me "table doesn't exist".
This proves that I dind't drop it, because if I was working in the page table structure of the table it means that the table was there.
And I don't know what happened, seems totally irrational to me.
The table simply disappeared (autodropped) while I was working on it.

However, doesn't matter so much what happened. The question is: how can I restore the table? Given the fact that I didn't drop the table, maybe the table is still somewhere?

Comment: Well if the error says `table does not exist` maybe the Mysql gremlins did it.

Comment: Does the table appear in the left hand side menu

Comment: you mean like gizmo or the evil gremlins? @RiggsFolly

Comment: @RiggsFolly this is true - once had a table **and** a chair stolen by the MySQL gremlins once. Tut tut

Comment: @RaymondNijland Oh Gizmo would never so anything as nasty as that.... surley :)

Comment: I would definitely suggest restoring the table from your last backup .....:) ...... wait for it

Comment: You could try a simple logout and then log backin to phpMyAdmin. Maybe it got itself a little confused and a restart may straighten it out

Comment: *"I was trying to drop a column of my table but I got an error message."* *"table doesn't exist"* Then you get scared and you find out that most likely you dropt your table instead of dropping a column because computers can not tell a lie.. like @RiggsFolly said restore it from a backup..

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the table was dropped and an error occured **after** the table got dropped. Double triple check in PHPMyAdmin, but I think your table has gone forever.

To prevent this happening in the future, always run daily backups on your site and store them in a location that's not on the server hosting your database.